# Is it possible to define multiple lambda destinations in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have the following lambda function in AWS CDK:

```
checker_destination = lambda_destinations.LambdaDestination(checker_function)
sns_destination = lambda_destinations.SnsDestination(monitoring_topic)
    
    rls_function = _lambda.Function(
        #Other parameters left out for this question since they are not relevant
        on_success=checker_destination, 
        on_failure=checker_destination
    )
```

However, I also want to add the sns destination to the on_failure parameter. Is this possible in AWS Cdk? on_failure expects a destination, and not an array of destinations so [checker_destination,sns_destination] does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but that is not a limitation of the CDK but of the Lambda service itself, you can only have one success and failure target each, not multiple. See [`DestinationConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_DestinationConfig.html) in the API.

If you want multiple targets you need to create the fan-out yourself and e.g. specify SNS as the target and then subscribe multiple things to that SNS topic.